# collapsible sidebar.....want to fix the header and footer part of sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my web page sidebar appears when clicked upon a particular icon.In the sidebar-footer there is a text box whose input runs on a particular php page and output gets printed on sidebar-main. I want to fix the sidebar-header and sidebar-footer relative to sidebar (i.e., when sidebar is active).Only sidebar-main should scroll when content grows. As of now whole sidebar scrolls. Thank you in advance!

```css
  #bot {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50;
  left: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  /* full screen */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* transparent black */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  /* middle layer, i.e. appears below the sidebar */
  z-index: 9998;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -350px;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #26a0da, #314755);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
  left: 0;
}

#dismiss {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
  right: 20;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 998;
  display: none;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #26a0da, #314755);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-menu {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  #position: fixed;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-footer {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #26a0da, #314755);
  text-align: center;
  #position: fixed;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <!-- Close Sidebar Button -->
    <div id="dismiss">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Header -->
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Sidebar-Header</h3>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Main -->
    <div class="sidebar-main">
      <div id="result"></div>
      <!-- Result comes from javascript part -->
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Footer -->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <div id="message-box" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="" placeholder="Messages" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

  <div id="sidebarCollapse">
    <img src="icon2.png" id="bot">
  </div>

  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to simplify your code to avoid including elements that are not part of the question (like the sidebar's "active" class), as your snippet doesn't actually show anything. Also using a relative path for an image on a snippet doesn't really work.

On the other hand, it is not clear if your sidebar's header and footer are meant to be fixed height or not (or the whole sidebar). In the first case, it can be handled with CSS alone as seen in [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/x7mkLcy1/4/).

You may want to add a container for your menu and set a fixed height for that container (screen size - header height - footer height).

HTML

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <!-- Header content -->
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <div class="menu-container">
            <!-- Menu content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <!-- Footer content -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    width:350px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100vh;
}

.sidebar-header {
    height:100px;
    position:relative; /* doesn't need to be absolute */
    width:100%
}

.sidebar-footer {
    height:100px;
    position:absolute; /* the footer goes to the bottom */
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%
}

.menu-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 200px); /* screen height - header height - footer height */
    overflow: auto; /* this makes your container div to scroll if the content's overflowing */
}
```

If you want automatic heights for the footer or header of the sidebar (which I don't recommend), then you should set the sidebar's header and footer height from javascript and then calculate the menu container's height and set it from code.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers.